# SQL Server Compact timed out waiting for a lock

Tags: timeout, locking, sql-server-ce

I'm having an application in that i use Sql Compact 3.5 with VS2008. I'm running multiple threads in my application which contacts the compact database and accesses the row. It selects and deletes those rows in a fashion i.e selecting and giving to the application 5 rows and deleting those rows from the table. It works great with a single thread but if i use multiple threads i.e if 3 or more threads are running I get very often the TimeOut Error!!! I have increased the Time out property in the connection string but it didn't give me expected result. The error log is as follow:

SQL Server Compact timed out waiting for a lock. The default lock time is 2000ms for devices and 5000ms for desktops. The default lock timeout can be increased in the connection string using the ssce: default lock timeout property. [ Session id = 5,Thread id = 4204,Process id = 4808,Table name = XXX,Conflict type = x lock (s blocks),Resource = TAB ]

The Query that I use to retrieve is as follows:

"
select Top(5) * from TableName order by id;
delete from TableName where id in(select top(5) id from TableName order by id);
"

Is there any way by which we can avoid this Time Out exception???????

The above query I un as a transaction in VS2008 one using SQLCECommand and the other using SqlCEDataAdapter.

Any Idea!!!!!!
Reply

Answer (score 2):

I've had exactly the same problem.  I know this is an old question but for anyone Googling for an answer I fixed it by calling Reader.Close() on my dataReader when I'd finished with it.

The application was single threaded but I was getting this all the time if I made too many requests too quickly.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are some connection string settings you can try, like "default lock timeout", and so on.

See [SqlCeConnection.ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring(VS.80).aspx) at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring(VS.80).aspx.

(I had nothing but trouble chaining queries with the semi-colon.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now...

The issue was that I had done an `ALTER` table in a transaction and then tried to read from that table later in the same transaction. oops. Removed the `ALTER` table from the transaction and everything is wonderful again.

Answer (score 0):

Although multi threading with SQLCE is possible the database is very limited to concurrent transactions.

Encapsulating every SQLCE related class that implements IDisposable in using statements is definitly a good idea but lock error might still occur depending on load.

None of the connection string timeout options seem to solve that.
As a workaround I just retry the operation in case of a lock error.

Note that the big SQL server does not suffer on this. Parallel processing works without any issues.